# Why is the concentration of hydrogen peroxide given as a percentage? For example, 3%, 6%

Tags: concentration

Conventionally, the concentration of solutions is given in moldm⁻³ or M, however, I am curious why the concentration of hydrogen peroxide isn't written in the same way.

Comment: Commercially provided liquids, like acids or alkoholic drinks,, are not provided with molarity either, but with mass or volume percentage ( unless being the precise concentration standard solution ). Like 35-37% HCl, 96-98% H2SO4 or 40% rum.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The concentration, if expressed in mol/L, has no meaning for usual people, who do not know what is a mole. That is why the concentration is expressed in percent. The percent unit is understood by everybody.